# Has anyone successfully used setExitTransition on L?

Tags: android, mobile, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I've been trying to use the new fancy animations that come with the L developer preview, but I'm having a lot of difficulties. In particular, I am not seeing any fancy animations. I'm trying to use the Explode exit transition. Here's the code:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // inside your activity
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

        // set an exit transition
        getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        // Find our button and add our click handler
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Transition to activity B
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of starting another activity using `startActivity(intent);` use the following statement.

```
startActivity(intent,ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
```

I started another activity as said above and it worked for me.

It's said in google documentation [Defining Custom Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html) as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem - you need the

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
```

call on the activity you are transitioning too as well!

Comment: Or just have your style inherit from `Theme.Material.***` and you'll get this for free.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // enable transitions
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    public void onSomeButtonClicked(View view) {
        getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent,
                      ActivityOptions
                          .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
    }
}
```

`requestFeature` in `onCreate` an `setExitTransition` before `startActivity`